# How to match the list of values in an IN clause with another IN clause in a linear manner

Tags: sql, oracle

```
--Table_1

col1    col2
............
123     abc
456     def
123     def


select * from Table_1 where col1 in (123,456) and col2 in (abc,def);
```

I want the output to match the row containing just '123' from "col1" and 'abc' from "col2" , and not '123' from col1 and 'def' from 'col2'.
The list in IN clause should match accordingly in a linear manner.

```
select * from Table_1 where col1 in (123,456) and col2 in (abc,def);
```

O/P

```
col1   col2
123    abc
456    def
```

Comment: why don't just state the condition in where clause like: where (col1 = 123 and col2 = 'abc') or (col1 = 456 and col2 = 'def')?

Comment: @assembly.jc  i have a huge list to put in col1 and col2 , the above method will be tedious

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih Oracle sql developer

Comment: @D-Shih, I was trying to understand your answer ,why did you remove it,it worked , can you write it back.

Comment: Because you accept another different answer so I just think I misunderstood you logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use tuples for comparison of a combination of multiple columns.

```
select *
from Table_1
where (col1,col2) in ( (123,'abc'),(456,'def'), (789,'abc') );
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2a0d0b448fb20120c3ee2f6d4dbdfd1c)

Comment: @senorelanza . . . This is the correct answer.  Oracle supports tuples with `in`.  I would recommend accepting this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `row_number` window function to make it.

```
SELECT col1,col2
from (
    select col1,col2,row_number() over(partition by col1 order by col2) rn
    from Table_1 
    where col1 in (123,456) and col2 in ('abc','def')
) t1
where rn = 1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd457556331020a7322e715ad086600b)

Comment: But all the values of "col2" should be manually entered by using this method

Comment: why the tables are joined by the total distinct "count", I don't understand, can you elaborate.

Comment: Because `cte2` will get the amount which is `col2` total, `cte1` will get amount by each `col1` then if amount from `cte2` equal to `cte1` means  `col1`  of `cte1` have full amount   @senorelanza

Comment: Okay,but there will be multiple distinct values, like col2 can have two or three distinct values and it is not possible to join the tables based on the "cnt" of  cte2 ,and also after joining, how is it possible to get records in a linear manner.

Comment: does the record 456 in col1 should be selected?

Comment: @senor elanza Could you edit your question and add more sample data and expect result?